# I had to create a dictionary from a table that had course names and their instructors, then get the name of an specific intructor

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is the code of the dictionary I have created from the table given (it works):

dic1a = {'Course':['Enfineering','Stochastics','SCM'],
'Instructor':['Katie', 'Michele', 'Li']}

dic1a

I need to get the name of the instructor for the Stochastics and SCM but I don't know how to do it. I would truly appreciate any help with this problem! Thank you

Comment: you should at least try your own homework first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that this is for an assignment of sorts. I don't know the prompt, but if you're looking to literally just print Michele and Li, the code would be as follows:

```
print(dic1a.get('Instructor')[1])
print(dic1a.get('Instructor')[2])
```

To print something to the console, you would use the print() method. To retrieve a specific value from a key, you would use get('key'), hence get('Instructor'). To retrive a specific value from the list inside of get('Instructor'), you would call the value [value], hence [1] and [2]. (The count starts at 0, so [0] would be Katie.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new dictionary that maps courses to instructors by zipping the two lists together. Then you can look them up directly:

```
dic1a = {'Course':['Enfineering','Stochastics','SCM'], 'Instructor':['Katie', 'Michele', 'Li']}

courses_to_instructor = dict(zip(dic1a['Course'], dic1a['Instructor']))

print(courses_to_instructor['Stochastics'])
print(courses_to_instructor['SCM'])

# prints:
# Michele
# Li
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this would be better, it makes sense to look them up directly.